# XQuartz keeps crashin with one xmate-session, but not for others nor for xmate on other debian

Tags: terminal, ssh, virtualization, x11, xquartz

I am ssh-ing into a Debian virtual machine that has xfce4 and mate installed.
In the past, they both worked fine.
Now, when I use Mate using Mac's terminal + XQuartz, it keeps crashing while looking for the best screen resolution.

When I do exactly the same with xfce4, on the same account of the same debian VM, everything works fine.

When I use MobaXterm on Windows to access this VM via ssh and using Mate, it works fine as well.

Also, when I use Mate with another Debian VM that I haven't tweeked much, it works fine even with XQuartz.

So it is currently only the interaction of my given Quartz on Mac + my given Mate settings on the Debian VM that makes it crash.

How can I go back to original settings of XQuartz when using Mate with this VM ?

I tried deinstalling and reinstalling, but that's not much better.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of XQuartz?

Comment: The latest one. Even after reinstalling it I have the same problem. Please note that xquartz works fine with xfce4 on the same virtual machine and works fine with mate on a different virtual machine. And that mobaxterm works fine on the same virtual machine with the same mate. So it's really about some cached settings,I would say.